# How to design a SQLite table using Anko in Kotin?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite, anko

I design a very simple table using Anko in Kotlin, there is a primary key named _id in the table and I hope the _id is passed value automatically by SQLite system.
I have read some sample code,but I don't know which one is correct, Method 1, Method 2 or Method 3?

And more, when I insert a record, I don't think I need to pass a value to _id, but the _id property of MSetting and DBSetting must be passed value, so I have to initial it with `MSetting(10L,"My Settings",2000L,"This is description!")`
I don't know how Anko handle the needless _id, and I'm very strange that the app don't crash when I execute `SettingManage().addSetting(MSetting(10L,"My Settings",2000L,"This is description!"))` repeatedly !

**Method 1:** `DBSettingTable._ID to INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY+ UNIQUE,`

**Method 2:** `DBSettingTable._ID to INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY+ AUTOINCREMENT,`

**Method 3:** `DBSettingTable._ID to INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY,`

**Insert Data**

```
SettingManage().addSetting(MSetting(10L,"My Settings",2000L,"This is description!"))
```

**Design Table**

```
class DBSettingHelper(mContext: Context = UIApp.instance) : ManagedSQLiteOpenHelper(
        mContext,
        DB_NAME,
        null,
        DB_VERSION) {

    companion object {
        val DB_NAME = "setting.db"
        val DB_VERSION = 5
        val instance by lazy { DBSettingHelper() }
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        db.createTable( DBSettingTable.TableNAME , true,
                DBSettingTable._ID to INTEGER + PRIMARY_KEY,
                DBSettingTable.Name to TEXT,
                DBSettingTable.CreatedDate to INTEGER,
                DBSettingTable.Description to TEXT
        )
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db.dropTable(DBSettingTable.TableNAME, true)
        onCreate(db)
    }

}



class DBSetting(val mMutableMap: MutableMap<String, Any?>) {
    var _id: Long by mMutableMap
    var name: String by mMutableMap
    var createdDate: Long by mMutableMap
    var description: String by mMutableMap

    constructor(_id: Long, name: String, createdDate: Long, description: String)
            : this(HashMap()) {
        this._id = _id
        this.name = name
        this.createdDate = createdDate
        this.description=description
    }
}


object DBSettingTable {
    val TableNAME = "SettingTable"

    val _ID = "_id"
    val Name = "name"
    val CreatedDate = "createdDate"
    val Description="description"
}
```

**Business Logic**

```
class SettingManage {
    fun addSetting(mMSetting:MSetting){
        DBSettingManage().addDBSetting(DbDataMapper().convertMSetting_To_DBSetting(mMSetting))
    }
}

class DBSettingManage(private val mDBSettingHelper: DBSettingHelper =DBSettingHelper.instance) {
    fun addDBSetting(mDBSetting: DBSetting)=mDBSettingHelper.use{
        insert(DBSettingTable.TableNAME,*mDBSetting.mMutableMap.toVarargArray())
    }
}

class DbDataMapper {
    fun convertMSetting_To_DBSetting(mMSetting: MSetting) =with(mMSetting){
        DBSetting(_id,name,createdDate,description)
    }
    fun convertDBSetting_To_MSetting(mDBSetting: DBSetting)=with(mDBSetting){
        MSetting(_id,name,createdDate,description )
    }
}


fun <T : Any> SelectQueryBuilder.parseList(parser: (Map<String, Any?>) -> T): List<T> =
        parseList(object : MapRowParser<T> {
            override fun parseRow(columns: Map<String, Any?>): T = parser(columns)
        })
```

Comment: I've never used the sqlite library of anko, but _"standard"_ sqlite (I believe android did not use the linux library) will default the value of every `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` to it's internal `rowid`, which is a unique and usually incrementing number for every row in the table

Comment: Thanks! Do I need  to delete  `this._id = _id`   in the code  `constructor(_id: Long, name: String, createdDate: Long, description: String)
            : this(HashMap()) {`